# IntelliJ 2018.1.3 shows all the methods from the interfaces, why?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Lets say we have the following code:

```
public interface Dvd {
   void startDvd();
}
```

and another interface:

```
public interface Tv {
    void startTv();
}
```

and a class:

```
public class Logitech implements Dvd, Tv {
    @Override
    public void startDvd() {

    }

    @Override
    public void startTv() {

    }
}
```

then when you make an instance:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tv tv = new Logitech();
        tv.  //here when we click the . we expect to see only the startTv() 
             //method, as the type of our reference is Tv
    }
}
```

however what is shown is:

[an image of my intellij code complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srnPA.png)

isn't this kind of invalidating the abstraction OOP concept as it will always show me all of the methods from the interfaces that my class implements, and sometimes this can be tons of methods will not hide any complexity for me?

Why do I see both methods and NOT only startTv()?

Comment: "Invalidating OOP concept"?  Of course not.  You need to see all the methods in your class.  If you have tons of methods, too many to view, that's your real problem.  Don't blame the IDE.

Comment: Can you confirm that clicking on `startDvd()` prompts you to change the variable type to Logitech ? It could be a smart assist, and not really a valid method.

Comment: @duffymo - I have only one class and two interfaces, what if the class implements 10 interfaces with 5 methods in each interface, that way I will see 50 methods in the code complete which I dont want to, I wanna see only the methods from Tv as the type of the reference is that one?

Comment: @JayPatel-PayPal the variable declaration does not change. It adds a cast so the line becomes `((Logitech) tv).startDvd();`

Comment: Only someone who actively designed that feature will be able to tell you. Probably the answer will be "because we wanted it to work that way".

Comment: If you have 10 interfaces you've got another problem to deal with.  IntelliJ is not an issue.

Comment: @JayPatel-PayPal yes it adds the cast but in the past you did not even see these methods, as if the class implements 10 interfaces with 10 methods, it will be hard to recognize which comes from the exact type of the reference and which are the ones that will get casted, too much methods shown bring complexity and abstraction is exactly about the opposite?

Comment: @Michael there you go. Basically IntelliJ actively looked at type casting, and saw that you might be interested in doing this. The above casting works as expected in OOP standards. I think IntelliJ is trying to be helpful here.

Comment: @Michael noooow that was a helpful answer, it all starts to make sense now I just tried it with an argument and it works as expected, it seems I have assumed that it will do it for the argument too and wasn't thinking about the local variable. Thanks Michael!

Comment: @MaxYearwood Sure. I've expanded my comment into an answer with some addition details if you're interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This only works for local variables, and only when IntelliJ is able to be sure that the type of the variable is always actually a certain concrete type (in this case `Logitech`).

If we add another class which implements `Tv`

```
class Foo implements Tv {
    @Override
    public void startTv() { }
}
```

and then assign to the variable conditionally:

```
class Demo
{
    private static int bar()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    public static void main(Tv args) {
        Tv tv = new Logitech();

        if (bar() > 2)
        {
            tv = new Foo();
        }

        tv. //only has startTv method
    }
}
```

then IntelliJ is no longer able to infer the type, so it won't prompt us with methods from `Logitech` (or from `Foo` either).

This is also true for method arguments - IntelliJ does not know the true concrete type, so it won't provide you any additional methods.

Comment: Thank you Michael! Now that throws some light to why it happens, the fact that I still do not like it is my own problem, :) as it was a different behavior in the past with all the IDEs. From now on why would I bother to write Tv tv = new Logitech();   (assuming that the lines of code with the Foo class is non-existent) when I can always write Logitech tv = new Logitech() it will be totally the same behavior, I will always see all of the methods.

Comment: I want Intellij make a setting options to show only methods of interface instead of class.

Answer (score 4):

It's kind of assistance provided by IntelliJ, if you press `enter` after select `startDvd()`, it'll replace your code in         `((Logitech) tv).startDvd();`

If you remove this cast, you'll get classic `cannot resolve method 'startDvd()'`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but normally in any previous version and any other Java IDE is **NOT** showing all the methods from the interfaces that are implemented by the class, but only the ones from which is the exact type of the reference(which in our case is Tv and we're supposed to be shown only  startTv()).

I cannot even see a setting to make it work like as it was with 2017 version of IntelliJ, if someone is aware it would be highly appreciated?

Comment: Moreover the idea of the Abstraction OOP concept is hiding the complexity, not showing more complexity. If I wanted to see all the methods in the code complete why would I bother to make an instance using Tv as a type of my reference, I can always write Logitech tv = new Logitech() and I would again see all the methods. Just don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Secretly the tv object is an instance of the Logitech class. Intellij is trying to help by letting you know that you *can* access the startDvd() method if you want to by using a cast.

Kind of a long way of telling you that you can cast the Tv back into a Logitech.

However if all the program needs at that time is a TV object probably better to set tv to a class that *implements* the Tv interface directly.

Alternatively you might want to implement it anonymously:

```
    Tv tv = new Tv() {
        public void startTv() {
            //code to start the tv
        }
    }
```